# How to delete my new app and publish it again?

Tags: android, google-play

I published a new app on the play store it hasn't gone live yet it is still being reviewed. can I delete the app because I want to change the package name and publish it again. the app status is "in review".

Comment: How come the app pushed to Android play store is in review by 'Apple' ?

Comment: it's a mistake just edited it

Comment: You have to unpublished

Answer (score 0):

Once you uploaded an app to the Google Play Console, you can't change the package name of the app. To change the package name you would need to create an entirely new application in the play store console and unpublish the older app.

Once you publish an app you can't delete the app as every package name is unique and can be used only once. In your case unpublish the older one and create a new app in play console.

Comment: how do I delete the older one? and would google approve it since it's the same app as the older one?

Comment: does google approve it if it's the same app as the previous one but with a different package name?

Comment: @MjSal Yes but you can unpublish.

Comment: I would say, since you are the owner of this package name. Just change what you wanna change in the app ( like name, or whatever improvement ) and publish it under the same package name with greater version. Package name is irrelevant for end user, si why to change it? If you improvement make the app totally different, then create a new package name and depreciate the you old package from play store. The only thing you can't do, same package name free to pay. The things you should not do, same package nam with new restrictive new permission

Comment: @TeddySmith actually package name is the only thing I want to change. it has my name in it I'm afraid it will affect the app search ranking because it is not related to the app title that will be listed in the play store.

Comment: I don't think the search ranking is mainly affected by the package name. Since you can have many name for the same package name. (cf- different name depending of the country) So I think the ranking search has nothing to do with your package name.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, If your app is not going to live on playStore and you wanna some changes in your app or this is your first release and u have not any release live on playStore then simpaly go to your play Conole -->

1. Console
2. All Apps --> Find your app which app you wanna change or first release uploads/changes
3. select app and Delete it work when your app is not live..
4. Modify/change your app / add features , do the stuff.
5. Again you have need to create a new app on your console
   [follow this pattern](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p2eon.png)
6. and do the same stuff for package name *, uploading images for your app
7. when you complete your basic then go for create release
8. Upload your app and your app uploaded successfully.

If U wanna [permanent private then follow](https://support.google.com/googleplay/work/answer/9146439?hl=en)

Comment: I cannot find the delete option

Comment: @MjSal You can't delete a published app. Please unpublish, that's all you can do for changing the package name.